# render python dictionary on html page

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-sse

I have taken the following code from https://github.com/coderspage/flask-sse.

I am trying to render dictionary continuously from the backend.

I know how to render dictionary using jinja template engine, but don't know how can I render it here.

can anyone tell me how to do this?

**server.py**

```
@app.route("/listen")
def listen():

  def respond_to_client():
    while True:

      df = pd.read_csv(filename)
      df['link_tuple'] = list(zip(df.fut_link, df.option_link))
      final_dict = pd.Series(df.link_tuple.values, index=df.symbol).to_dict()
      _data = json.dumps(final_dictionary)


      yield f"id: 1\ndata: {_data}\nevent: online\n\n"
      time.sleep(0.5)
  return Response(respond_to_client(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

.

**index.html**

```
<body>
   
  // render data object here

  <script>
    var eventSource = new EventSource("/listen")
    
    eventSource.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
      console.log(e.data)
    }, false)

    eventSource.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
      
     let data = JSON.parse(e.data)
 
      
    }, true)

  </script>

</body>
```

.

**data  object**

```
 {
    "ASIANPAINT24JUN21FUT": [
    "https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:ASIANPAINT1!",
    "https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/ASIANPAINT21JUN2980CE/15044354"
    ],
    "DEEPAKNTR24JUN21FUT": [
    "https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:DEEPAKNTR1!",
    "https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/DEEPAKNTR21JUN1820CE/20372738"
    ],
    "DRREDDY24JUN21FUT": [
    "https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:DRREDDY1!",
    "https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/DRREDDY21JUN5350CE/20732162"
    ],
    "ESCORTS24JUN21FUT": [
    "https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:ESCORTS1!",
    "https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/tvc/NFO-OPT/ESCORTS21JUN1220CE/20892674"
    ] 
}
```

Comment: you have to learn JavaScript because `jinja` can work only on server and it is useless in your code. Eventually you can use `jinja` to generate some HTML and `yield` it but still you will have to use JavaScript to insert/replace it in web browser.

Comment: in your link there is `index.html` which shows you how to replace HTML in browser - `document.querySelector("#counter").innerText = data.counter` - and similar way you may replace HTML which you get from server. OR you will have to learn JavaScript to generate HTML in JavaScript